# Stacked Bar Chart widget inside a grid cell

Tags: javascript, extjs

I know, that modern `ExtJS` supports really wonderful [widget columns](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/#widget-grid). However, what I'm missing is a horizontal stacked bar chart inside a grid cell. In practice, that would allow me to show for example how much of something is in progress, delayed, postponed etc. per each row that may be a person, a department or something like that. This is what I want to achive (made in Paint):

[image]

If such a widget column does not exist by default, I hope someone can advise how to implement it.

Comment: you could use bootstrap stacked progress bar [http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-stacked](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-stacked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own component to use as the widget to nest in the column.
The dataIndex of the widget column would bind to an object with the percentage of each stage (which should add up to 100%) that looks like

```
{
    redPercent: 10,
    orangePercent: 20,
    bluePercent: 30,
    greenPercent: 40
}
```

Then the newly defined component would use a tpl to display the progress bar - using CSS to correctly set the percentage widths.

```
Ext.define('my.StatusBar', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

    xtype: 'my-status-bar',
    defaultBindProperty: 'statusCounts',
    config: {
        statusCounts: null
    },

    updateStatusCounts: function (obj) {
        this.getViewModel().set('statusCounts', obj);
    },

    viewModel: {
        data: {
            statusCounts: null
        }
    },

    height: 25,
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'middle'
    },

    constructor: function (config) {
        config.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'component',
                flex: 1,
                tpl: [
                    '<div style="width:100%; display:table;">',
                    '   <tpl if="redPercent"><div style="width: {redPercent}%; display:table-cell; background-color:red;"></div></tpl>',
                    '   <tpl if="orangePercent"><div style="width: {orangePercent}%; display:table-cell; background-color:orange;"></div></tpl>',
                    '   <tpl if="bluePercent"> <div style="width: {bluePercent}%; display:table-cell; background-color:blue;"></div></tpl>',
                    '   <tpl if="greenPercent"><div style="width: {greenPercent}%; display:table-cell; background-color:green;"></div></tpl>',
                    '</div>'
                ],
                bind: '{statusCounts}'
            }
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

And finally you would configure the widget column as

```
{
    xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
    text: 'Progress',
    dataIndex: 'statusCounts',
    widget: {
        xtype: 'my-status-bar'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try using the sparklinebar widget instead, this one can take an array of values unlike progressbar widget... sparklinebar does the bars vertically, but I know one can rotate the rendered canvas element.. 90deg, in your case. Not sure if this will work, just an idea..

Best of luck.

Comment: Actually, I did it using bootstrap stacked progress bar and column renderer. But still, thanks for sharing ideas.